# TypeError: fs.reddirSync is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, discord.js, fs

This is the code I have and I am not for sure what I am doing wrong.

```
const fs = require('fs')

module.exports = (client, Discord) =>{
    const command_files = fs.reddirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endWith('.js'));
    
    for(const file of command_files){
        const command = require(`../commands/${file}`);
        if(command.name){
            client.commands.set(command.name, command);
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you have a typo in readdirSync. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-fs-readdirsync-method/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct method is readdirSync, you have reddirSync:

```js
const command_files = fs.reddirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endWith('.js'));
```

Correct word:

```js
const command_files = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endWith('.js'));
```